# Renaming the alias in tableau

Tags: alias, renaming, tableau-api

How can I rename the alias in calculated field? I have calculated field "area" which display the integer values of the areas. I want to display each area as string as a data type, naming as "area coordinate A" and "area coordinate B" and so on. The values of each area coordinated are dynamic thus the naming should change automatically. Do I need to change function in calculated field?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you'll want to filter the *"coordinate A"* and the *"coordinate B"* in your formula, doing something like that:

[image]

You'll have to do it twice, so you'll have two fields, one for each coordinate. And then you'll be able to have different aliases.

PS: For asking a good question on Stack Overflow, I recommend reading [their guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I actually want to display integer values as string. I don't know which formula to use in calculation field. And my integer values are not static. I am calculating the area of the rectangles and each rectangle has different area. Instead of displaying the value of the area, I want to display as "coordinate A" and "coordinate B "etc.

Comment: Maybe you can use the STR() function? It returns a string given an expression, such as STR([area]) will return the number as a string.